# Need help identifying this plant, not sure what it is

Tags: identification, houseplants

Can someone help me identify this plant? Overall size is 2ft (60cm) and leaves are about 4 inches (10cm).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Hoya carnosa, but not sure

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a very unhappy ZZ plant, it is hanging instead of standing up straight. Make sure you have proper drainage and don't keep the soil wet all the time.

The plants suffer probably from root rot caused by too wet soil. The rotting roots are not able to take up water and the plant starts to hang (and eventually die). Make sure the soil dries up a bit in between watering so the rot can stop and new roots can form. When the root system is healthy again, water it when the soil is dry like half a finger deep. It should stand up straight again then hopefully.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes it does have drainage holes. This plant was left behind by the previous tenant, so I wasn’t sure what kind it was.

Comment: I think your plants hangs because of too much water, maybe try to give it less frequently water.

Comment: How can I make it go back straight? Should I put wooden sticks to help it?

Comment: See previous comment, less water should help them recover

Comment: Thanks for the help